# Does the concept of linear transformation capture all subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $y$-axis in the $xy$-plane, which we can think of as spanned by, say, the vector (0, 1). This is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, this line is not a function, so it seems like it doesn’t really correspond to a linear transformation which is by definition a function. For example, this subspace cannot be the image of a linear transformation. However, it is a perfectly normal subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$: it is just a line through the origin, generated by a non-zero vector in that line. In this sense, it is basically the same as all other lines through the origin.

My question is: Do we “lose” anything by only considering linear transformations, which are functions, instead of say allowing for non-functions (that arise quite naturally in the context of subspaces, like in the example above)? Of course, a big reason for focusing on functions is because they are ubiquitous and a very important type of relation. But, do we ever want to allow for non-functions? Suppose, for example, that we want the idea of “image” to be, in some sense, as general as possible, in particular allowing for all possible subspaces of the codomain to be considered. Is this even a useful/practical concern?

Comment: The y axis is an image of the projection mapping, i.e. $T(x,y)=(0,y) $ contrary to what you have said.

Comment: @Shahab I think the point is that the $y$-axis is not the graph of a function, meaning it is not a linear subspace of the form $\{(x, Tx) : x \in \Bbb{R}\}$ for some transformation $T$.

Comment: @Shahab Oh gosh, sorry, I just realized I confused functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with linear transformations from the plane to itself... Is that where I went wrong? Confusing graphs of functions with linear maps from a vector space to itself?

Comment: The last sentence seems to indicate otherwise. I think the OP wants to know,  given a subspace of the codomain is it always true that there exists a linear transformation mapping to it. The answer is no, but the example given by the OP isn't the appropriate example.

Comment: @Shahab That's interesting, do you have an example for that? I thought that given a subspace $U$, we can just look at the orthogonal projection onto $U$? Isn't the image of this just $U$? Edit: However I think the orthogonal projection is only valid for operators, so yeah, I'm not considering cases where the domain and codomain are different.

Comment: @Shahab I guess if the dimension of the domain is less than the codomain, then we can't possibly reach every subspace via a linear map, for example we can't reach the codomain. But what about the case when the dimension of the domain is greater than or equal to that of the codomain?

Comment: Yes your guess is correct because the rank nullity theorem would be violated if we supposed otherwise. In the latter case you can always find a linear transformation by sending a basis of the domain to a basis of the image arbitrarily.

Comment: @Shahab Every subspace of a vector space is the image of _some_ linear transformation. You seem to be assuming a fixed domain. I see nothing in the question that would warrant that assumption.